# How to extract "Multi-value Select Combo Box" in Apache Commons File Upload?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons, multipart

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that my multiple combox box is a "transfer type" selction, wherein you select multiple options from one box and I have a ">" button to transfer the selected values to another multiple combobox.  The problem was the transferred values need to be highlighted before submission.  It was just not natural from a user's POV having to need to highlight his selection again after transferring, so I just added a script to automatically do that when submitting the form.

---

I have a form that is *enctype="multipart/form-data"*. One of the elements is a multi-value SELECT combo box:

```
<select multiple name="fromBox" id="fromBox">
```

Now in my servlet, I use the Apache Common File Upload to parse and iterate through the request.  It iterates fine on the other regular form fields and I'm able to get their values, but it doesn't seem to include the multiple value combo box above.

I displayed all the field names that it iterates through via the code below and the field name "fromBox" is not being listed.

```
    if (item.isFormField()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("***THE FIELD NAME: " + item.getFieldName());
                .....
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What other regular form fields have you tried? Looking at the Commons FileUpload docs, it says that `FileUpload` parses HTTP requests which conform to [RFC 1867, "Form-based File Upload in HTML"][2]. Just trying to determine if <select> is supported.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally put this select outside the form.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my multiple combox box is a "transfer type" selction, wherein you select multiple options from one box and I have a ">" button to transfer the selected values to another multiple combobox.  The problem was the transferred values need to be highlighted before submission.  It was just not natural from a user's POV having to need to highlight his selection again after transferring, so I just added a script to automatically do that when submitting the form.